# I want to Save Maps in JSON File from Selenium Scrape data

Tags: python, json, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, python-jsonschema

I scraped a website and I get all the data from it and I want store it in json file
so I could use it as an API the problem is that when it tries to write  maps in JSON file it get duplicated because I called json.dumps inside for loop this is what I try to do

How can I append to chapters list and keep the title the same I have more books also it gonna be a list

```
{
  "title":"Kingdom",
   "chapters":[
    {
      "chapter-title": "Kingdom - 12",
      "images" : [
        "image1.jpg",
        "image2.jpg",
        "image3.jpg"
      ]
    }{
      "chapter-title": "Kingdom - 13",
      "images" : [
        "image1.jpg",
        "image2.jpg",
        "image3.jpg"
      ]
    }{
      "chapter-title": "Kingdom - 14",
      "images" : [
        "image1.jpg",
        "image2.jpg",
        "image3.jpg"
      ]
    }{
      "chapter-title": "Kingdom - 15",
      "images" : [
        "image1.jpg",
        "image2.jpg",
        "image3.jpg"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

and this is what I got :

```
{
  "title":"Kingdom",
   "chapters":[
    {
      "chapter-title": "Kingdom - 12",
      "images" : [
        "image1.jpg",
        "image2.jpg",
        "image3.jpg"
      ]
    }
  ]
}{
  "title":"Kingdom",
   "chapters":[
    {
      "chapter-title": "Kingdom - 13",
      "images" : [
        "image1.jpg",
        "image2.jpg",
        "image3.jpg"
      ]
    }
  ]
}{
  "title":"Kingdom",
   "chapters":[
    {
      "chapter-title": "Kingdom - 14",
      "images" : [
        "image1.jpg",
        "image2.jpg",
        "image3.jpg"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

```
def getAllImages(url=""):
    chrome_options = Options()
    chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")

    driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=chrome_options)

    try:
        driver.get(url)
        driver.implicitly_wait(2)
    except Exception as e:
        print("Error Getting Images Page :", e)

    print(driver.title)

    divs = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("page-break ")

    images = []
    for div in divs:
        image = div.find_elements_by_tag_name("img")

        [images.append(j.get_attribute("src").strip()) for j in image]

    chapters ={"chapter-title": driver.title, "images": images}

    list = [{"title":"Kingdom","chapters":[]}]
    list[0]["chapters"].append(chapters)
    
    toJson = json.dumps(list, ensure_ascii=False, indent=2)
    with open("./" + "manga.json", "r+") as f:
        if len(f.read()) == 0:
            f.write(toJson)
        else:
            f.write(",\n" + toJson)

    print("Successfully created ")

for url in links:
    getAllImages(url)
```

Comment: can you share the url?

Comment: without your url it will be difficult to help you